# Нужна ли запятая? (6)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

И всё же(,) можно его оправдать или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятую поставить можно и, вероятно, даже желательно.

[**ВСЁ Ж(Е) / ВСЁ Ж ТАКИ / ВСЁ-ТАКИ**, *частица*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_115)

> Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
>
> Слова ***а всё ж(е)***, ***а всё ж таки***, ***а всё-таки***, стоящие в начале предложения, могут отделяться запятой при интонационно-логическом подчеркивании.
>
> ***А всё же**, в чём дело?* А. Вампилов, Прошлым летом в Чулимске.